# Extension of a $F$-homomorphism where $F$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

The whole question looks like-

> Let $F, E$ and $K$ be fields such that $F\subseteq E\subseteq K$ and
>   $K$ is normal over $F$. Show that any $F$-homomorphism $\sigma :E\to
>  K$ can be extended to an $F$-automorphism of $K$.

Now, first of all I have to extend a homomorphism $\sigma$ into an automorphism. So, here $\sigma$ must be injective. So, we have to first prove the injectiveness of $\sigma$. Am I right?
But I cannot extend this $F$-homomorphism to an $F$-automorphism. How to extend it?
Can anybody help me in this regard? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Injectiveness is automatic for morphisms of fields.

Comment: @ArnaudD. But how to extend it?

Comment: Think about writing $K$ as a vector space over $F$.

Comment: @RhythmInk, I can't get that, I can't extend the homomorphism just by thinking $K$ as a vector space over $F$, I have also need to use the normality condition, can you explicitly give the way out?

Comment: You can extend it that way. A $K$-linear extension is in particular a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear extension. That is, an extension of a homomorphism of abelian groups.